# Three.js - troubles with the size of texture

Tags: javascript, three.js

Less words, more code =)

```
var objects = [];

var camera, scene, renderer;

document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );

init();
render();

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
    var ray = new THREE.Ray( camera.position, vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );
    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( objects );
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        console.log(intersects[ 0 ].object);
    }
}

function init() {

    container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1100 );
    camera.position.z = 50;
    scene.add( camera );


    var particle = new THREE.Particle( new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "img/satellite.png" ) } ) );
    objects.push( particle );
    //particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = 0.25
    scene.add( particle );

    projector = new THREE.Projector();
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
}

function render() {
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

As a result, we get clickable particle with a texture. But I don't understand several things:

1. Why the "clickable" area of particle is so small? It works only if I click in the middle of a particle.
2. Why is that particle so huge? The texture is this [image: 16×16] .png file and the particle is way more bigger than 16×16. How can I fix that? Yes, I know about particle.scale, that will make particle look smaller. But, the "clickable" area of particle woukd also become smaller.

Comment: That's an interesting problem. Maybe we can add some code to `Ray` so the particle area cutomisable... Do you mind reporting it as a feature request on the github page?

Comment: Sure, https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2170

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I came across the same issue today and i found this question unanswered, after some workaround i came across a solution for this.

The solution is to create 2 particles, one as a simple particle that draws a geometry (rect or arc) that is a ParticleCanvasMaterial and then the particle that displays the image on top of it.

So you can use the ParticleCanvasMaterial to track the intersections and display the other particle as a dummy object where it's only purpose is displaying an image on the 3D scene.

A little bit of code:

```
var programFill = function (context) {
                context.beginPath();
                context.rect(-0.5, -0.38, 1, 1);
                //context.fill(); 
            }

            //creating particle to intersect with.
            var p = new THREE.ParticleCanvasMaterial({ program: programFill, transparent: true }); 
            var particle = new THREE.Particle(p);
            particle.scale.set(23, 23);
            //use same position for both particle and imgParticle
            particle.position.set(200, 300, 200);

            //creating particle that displays image.
            var imgTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/image.png');
            var p2 = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
                map: imgTexture
                , size: 1
            });

            var imgParticle = new THREE.Particle(p2);
            imgParticle.scale.x = 0.5;
            imgParticle.scale.y = 0.5; 
            imgParticle.position.set(200, 300, 200);
```